# How to use jQuery and PHP to show/hide a div depending on the date?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have been developing a website events page where I would like a small badge to display beside an event if it happens to take place on the current date.

I have stored my events in a database, where all dates are saved using the DATE data type. On the events page, information is retrieved using PHP/SQL.

I have created a script with jQuery to show the 'todayAlert' div when the date of an event matches the current date. Otherwise the div is meant to remain hidden. Unfortunately I can't get the script to work and the div is always hidden on the first event and always displayed with the following events. Can anyone help work out how to fix the script?

Code:

```
        <div class='row'>
        <!--Fetch and display events from database for SLIDE 1 -->          
        <?php

        $query = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY eventDate DESC LIMIT 3;";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                $event = $row["eventName"];
                $date = $row["eventDate"];
                $time = $row["eventTime"];
                $loc = $row["eventPlace"];  
                $desc = $row["eventDesc"]; 

            echo " <div id='eventCard' align='center' class='col-md-4'>

              <hr>

              <h3>$event</h3>
              <br>
              <p><i class='far fa-calendar-times'></i> ". date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date)) ."     <div id='todayAlert'><span class='badge badge-pill badge-danger'>Today!</span></div>
              <br>
              <i class='fas fa-map-marker-alt'></i> $loc
              <br>
              <i class='far fa-clock'></i> $time
              <br>
              <br>
              <a href='events.php'>More Info </a>
              </p>
              <hr>

              </div>

        <script>
        //show/hide event today alert depending on date
        var today = new Date();


        if(today.getDate() === $date){
            $('#todayAlert').show();
        } else {
            $('#todayAlert').hide();
        }
        </script>


            ";

             }

        } else {

            echo "

                <div id='eventCard' align='center' class='col-md-4'>
                <h1>No Results! <i class='fas fa-exclamation-circle'></i></h1>
                </div>

          ";

        }

        ?>

        </div>
```

Note- also using Bootstrap v 4.4.1,
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with JS/jQuery? PHP is totally capable of comparing dates and adding some information based on that. Try to think about that way of solving your problem.

Comment: @flomei thanks, yes I've already worked it out using PHP and posted the solution below earlier.

Comment: Sorry, didn't saw that in the post review screen. Good you got that running! :-)

Answer (score 0):

`today.getDate()` returns the current day of the month and it looks like `$date` contains day/month/year (not necessarily in that order). So when you compare the two it will always be false.

Comment: ok, thanks. Is there another way to compare them accurately? Also yes, $date contains the day/month/year in yy-mm-dd format.

Answer (score 0):

I've since solved this using pure PHP:

```
        <!--Fetch and display events from database for SLIDE 2 -->          
        <?php

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `events` ORDER BY `eventDate` DESC LIMIT 3 OFFSET 3;";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                $event = $row["eventName"];
                $date = $row["eventDate"];
                $time = $row["eventTime"];
                $loc = $row["eventPlace"];  
                $desc = $row["eventDesc"]; 

                $today = date("Y-m-d");

        echo " <div id='eventCard' align='center' class='col-md-4'>
               <hr>
               <h3>$event</h3> 
               <br>
               <p><i class='far fa-calendar-times'></i> ". date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date)) ." ";


        echo " ".($today == $date ? "<span class='badge badge-pill badge-danger'>Today!</span>" : "")." ";

        echo"

              <br>
              <i class='fas fa-map-marker-alt'></i> $loc
              <br>
              <i class='far fa-clock'></i> $time
              <br>
              <br>
              <a href='events.php'>More Info </a>
              </p>
              <hr>

              </div>

            ";

             }

        } else {

            echo "

                <div id='eventCard' align='center' class='col-md-4'>
                <h1><i class='fas fa-exclamation-circle'></i> No Results!</h1>
                </div>

          ";

        }

        ?>

        </div>
```